# Send Request to Web Connector using my Application Quick Books

Tags: asp.net, web-services, desktop, quickbooks

I want to Add Customer by sending request to Web Connector. I have done with the sample code provided by the SDK. I want to know the process of getting and sending data using Web Connector.

How can i call Quick Book Web Service and send request and retrieve data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can i call Quick Book Web Service

You can't.

That is not the way that the QuickBooks Web Connector works.

You're starting point should be to read the 98-page PDF about the QuickBooks Web Connector included with the QuickBooks SDK. Here's a link:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBWC_proguide.pdf

As an overview, the way the Web Connector is a simple SOAP client that sits next to QuickBooks and *it calls your web service*, not the other way around. It polls a web service (SOAP) that you set up and essentially asks "Hey, what should I do?" over and over again. You then give it XML (qbXML) commands telling it what to do (e.g. `<CustomerAdd>...</CustomerAdd>`, etc.)

As an overview, you implement a SOAP web service with these methods:

`array authenticate(string strUserName, string strPassword)`

You should have the username and password stored in your web app.

If the username and password are valid, you generate a session ID (a “ticket”) and store this ticket in your database. Every subsequent call to you will include this ticket string, and you'll check to ensure the ticket is valid on every subsequent call.

You should then check to see if there is anything to do. You should be maintaining a queue of things to do within your SOAP server. Return an appropriate response per the spec.

`string sendRequestXML(string ticket, string strHCPResponse, string strCompanyFileName, string qbXMLCountry, int qbXMLMajorVers, int qbXMLMinorVer)`

The Web Connector will call this method to ask you "Hey, what should I do?".

You should check your internal queue of things to do, and pull the next item out of the queue. You should return a valid qbXML XML request for that queue item as a string.

So if you wanted to add a customer to QuickBooks, you'd return something like `<CustomerAdd><Name>...</Name></CustomerAdd>`

If you wanted to get a list of customers from QuickBooks, you can do something like `<CustomerQuery>...</CustomerQuery>`

`integer receiveResponseXML(string ticket, string response, string hresult, string message)`

This is how the Web Connector sends data back to you. So for example, if you told the Web Connector to add a customer, it's going to add the customer to QuickBooks and then send you an XML response telling you if it was successful or not.

*That's all there is to it.*

You need to implement a SOAP service with 3 very simple methods, and a queue full of XML commands.

A larger explanation, complete with SOAP and qbXML examples is here:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector

If you're developing in .NET, then you should install the QuickBooks SDK:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0020_get_set_up/sdk_downloads

Because it *provides you with sample code in .NET which shows you how to implement all of this stuff*. It gets put here on your computer when you install the SDK:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\IDN\QBSDK13.0\samples\qbdt\c-sharp\qbXML\WCWebService\

Comment: It means only when the web connector calls the web service i need to give my query request? That is well and fine. Now the scenario is i have registered ten customers from my web application. How will the web connector know that it needs to add these ten customers?

Comment: Should i have any thing that stores this request and sends when the service is called?

Comment: The Web Connector can be configured to reach out to your web service every minute. When it connects, you tell it to add the customer by returning a <CustomerAdd> request from sendRequestXML. Yes, you should maintain a queue.

Comment: can you give me any suggestion? I have my application where I will register tenants and the data is stored in the database. When the web service is called should I query my database for recent records ? and give the add query to the web connector. I am very near to get what I want.

Comment: Yes, you should query the database. Lots of qbXML examples here: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests

Comment: I tried to query by connecting to database. but in web connector log I am getting xml parse error.Even my xml is in correct format it gives me the same error. I have queried my database and got some customer to insert.

Comment: is your XML valid? What does it look like?